# Thumbnails stopped working in GNOME

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 20.04, thumbnails

After a system clean-up, my Nautilus doesn't show thumbnails for new
images any more.  I reinstalled every package with the words “thumbnail”
or “preview” in description, but nothing works.  What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably removed the package `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin`.
Reinstall with:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
```

Comment: Awesome :) This solved the same problem for me on Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS.